# Issue parsing XML, unknown encoding

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding, xml-parsing, simplexml

I'm trying to read an XML feed, I'm not sure the encoding is proper, but it's set to UTF-8 and when I try to parse it in PHP via SimpleXML, it errors on "BöðVar" (note the special "o" characters).

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$XMLOutputXMLObj = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
if($XMLOutputXMLObj !== FALSE)
{
//do stuff
}
```

This is all I get for an error:

> Entity 'ouml' not defined
>
> Entity 'eth' not defined

I tried using "mb_convert_encoding", in various ways, but that failed.

How can I resolve this issue for any character?  IE **WITHOUT manually replacing** ö with &214; (with # of course)?

Even better... is there a way to make it so SimpleXML doesn't care what it is parsing, as long as the tags are intact?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to escape the XML data in the node using the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` tags before and after the node's text/value? E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fmsdata>
  <result><![CDATA[Success !@#$%^&*()]]></result>
</fmsdata>
```

Comment: Oh, dur I forgot that I could do that!  Man I'm out of touch.  Still wish I could figure out how to do it without it though.  Ahhh it won't let me accept your answer yet.

Comment: Know what you mean about being out of touch... Last week I had to write a XML proxy/web service and it took me ages remembering all the restrictions that XML docs have.

The only let-down, is that CDATA tags only works on the nodes' content/value and not on tag attributes... There you will have to escape the strings.